# Not able to generate extracted_queries.json using persistgraphql

Tags: graphql

I am trying to generate `extracted_queries.json` file using [persistgraphql](https://github.com/apollographql/persistgraphql) cli utility but when I am running the following command

```
persistgraphql src/app/ --add_typename
```

it results in this error

```
Unable to process input path src/app/. Error message: 
Syntax Error GraphQL request (1:1) Unexpected <EOF>

1: 
   ^
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After looking for answers for a while I am able to make it work.
In my case, we have queries and mutations written in js files so below command worked for me

```
persistgraphql src/app --js --extension=js --add_typename
```